# exploiting HTTP HOST header based redirection in apache reverse proxy for intranet resource

Tags: apache, sockets, ssl, reverse-proxy

I'm looking for suggestion on a POC which I'm doing. I'm trying to solve a use case where in a user accesses the intranet websites from some corporate mobile app when he is not on corporate network (and he also does not want to connect to VPN on mobile). I want to make that intranet website available to him through Apache reverse proxy using Multihomed server concept where in **HOST** header will be read and the reverse proxy will pass(forward)  that request to the value present in HOST header. The catch here is that all these sites are not on same proxy but on different webservers having different internal IP like 192.x.x.1, 192.x.x.2 etc.

In my POC java app( which will be replaced by mobile app once the concepts works) opens **HTTPS** socket with reverse proxy( having public IP and DNS entry) and then the intranet site address e.g. x.mycomp.com which user requested will be put in to the HOST header. After this  the http request will be sent to the reverse proxy through the HTTPS socket created above.

The problem is that

1) if I create HTTP socket in place of HTTPS above then Im able to redirect to the website having entry in host header field, however its failing in case i use HTTPS Socket and I get bad request (400). I assume ( and correct also) here that as the SSL connection is terminating at proxy it can read the header value.

2) I wanted to check if my approach is not workable ot its workable but will have some issues which I can not foresee.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks jww for redirecting me to that site and will ask their too. But if you observe in 2nd question i wanted feedback on my understanding of reverse proxy configuration if using HOST header for sites not hosted on same server but on many different server is fine.